# What is the point of the DateTime class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date, time

The `DateTime` class seems redundant, and after reading this bit in the documentation for the Rails extension of the class, it also seems potentially dangerous:

> DateTimes aren’t aware of DST rules, so use a consistent non-DST offset when creating a DateTime with an offset in the local zone

There's also this, in the Rails documentation for `DateTime#to_time`:

> Attempts to convert self to a Ruby Time object; returns self if out of range of Ruby Time class. If self has an offset other than 0, self will just be returned unaltered, since there’s no clean way to map it to a Time.

I assume that last part is due to `DateTime` not recognizing DST.

It seems to me we have this:

- The `Date` class represents a simple date without a time.
- The `Time` class represents a specific point in time, which implicitly includes the date.
- The `DateTime` class is the same as the `Time` class, but doesn't understand DST and sometimes can't convert to a regular `Time` class.

So should `DateTime` just be banished from the code base or does it serve a useful purpose which I am missing?

Comment: I tend to agree with you that usually what you want is Time, not DateTime... I've only ever worked with DateTime because it was already a DateTime... I've never opted to create one.  It's all a bit of a mess IMO.

Comment: Okay, there is one case where a DateTime is necessary: From the Rails documentation for `Time.time_with_datetime_fallback`: "Returns a new Time if requested year can be accommodated by Ruby’s Time class (i.e., if year is within either 1970..2038 or 1902..2038, depending on system architecture); otherwise returns a DateTime."

Comment: Is there any other case where a `DateTime` is unavoidable?

Comment: The only use I can think of is the greater range of `DateTime`. `Time is stored internally as the number of seconds with fraction since the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.`. So, you will not be able to use Time for dates earlier than that.eg. This errors as arguement out of range `Time.parse("01-01-1947 00:09:00")` but will work with `DateTime`.

Comment: In that case, it seems like `DateTime` is actually superior to `Time` _except_ in its inability to understand DST. It feels like too much ambiguity and too many gotchas to remember, and certainly a part of Ruby which would be ripe for improvement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` had an advantage over `Time` on 32 bit machines in Rubies < 1.9.2 - `Time` was a victim of the [Y2K38 problem](http://www.venombytes.com/2011/04/11/32-bits-of-ruby-in-time) and limited to a 32 bit range. This problem is solved either on 64 bit machines and/or in recent Ruby versions. You still may need to use `DateTime` if for example 1.8 compatibility is a must or you rely on using methods from its API which often deviates from that of `Time`.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Out of curiosity, do you know what the new range limits are for `Time`, if any?

Comment: @Chris Judging from the [sources](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/time.c), it seems like the current behavior is to use 64 bit precision whenever possible (uint64_t or long long or whatever is available). I haven't parsed the exact details yet, but I'd assume that, like illustrated in this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) article, regardless of the implementation details, there shouldn't be a real problem with ranges anymore when using 64 bits.

Comment: So it looks like we won't have to worry about this again until Sunday, 4 December 292,277,026,596. Thanks!